# How to execute command after grep match on output of first command

Tags: bash

I need to start a server kind of program (http-server), it run in the terminal and will output the port it is using when ready.
I want to wait until the port number is displayed and then run another command that will also be a server kind of program (run and accept user interaction)

I can get itto almost work with

```
http-server | (grep -m 1 "Server runing"; interactiveProgram)
```

InteractiveProgram will launch after grep match the first line but it won'tbe interactive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that with

```
http-server | (grep -m 1 "Server running"; interactiveProgram)
```

`interactiveProgram`’s standard input isn’t connected to the terminal, but piped from `http-server`’s standard output (once `grep` has finished with it).

```
http-server | (grep -m 1 "Server running"; interactiveProgram < /dev/tty)
```

should do what you’re after.

Comment: Thanks @pLumo, that is a bit of a blocker!

Answer (score 1):

If you run it as part of the pipe, stdin won't be connected with the terminal as @Stephen Kitt already said. But if you run it afterwards, it won't run before http-server has quit.

A workaround would be to use a `while`-loop with a `grep` call each line:

```
http-server | while read line; do
    echo "$line" | grep "Server running" && { interactiveProgram; break; }
done
```